# FileIFrameField with Parsing

Tags: php, file-io, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe 2.4.7 and I want to add a method that parses the file which I have just uploaded with FileIFrameField. The thing that has me stumped is where to put this. I was thinking of the onAfterWrite method but the file only gets uploaded after the rest of the fields have been saved for the first time so I'm not sure this would work.

My question is: What is the best practice for this kind of thing?

**Edit**

I have this line of code where $filename is the path to my uploaded file but I keep getting a "no such file or directory error".  I have even tried hardcoding in the filepath but get the same error.

```
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r');
```

Comment: so you're talking about a sitetree object, or a plain dataobject, managed via a complextablefield? behaviour is different, i think, as 'pages' are instantly saved to the db when created in the sitetree

Comment: No. Sorry I left out a big chunk of information there. I'm using DataObjectManager and one of the DataObjecta within that has this upload field.

Comment: could you go more into detail what you want to do with that file, I can't see what you are trying to do, so its hard to say where to do it.

Comment: Sure, what I want is to take in a file that has alphanumeric values on each line, parse it, and save each value to the database table.  I have gotten a bit further on my own but I have an error which is confusing me. I've put it in the edit in my question.

Comment: You should be able to take advantage of the onAfterWrite method on your File class. I believe if you use an alternative UploadField like Uploadify, you'll be able to upload the file before saving the DataObject you are editing / managing in DOM. https://github.com/unclecheese/Uploadify

Comment: I ended up getting it to work using the onAfterwrite method and raw SQL INSERT INTO.  Quite simple in the end. Thanks for all the advice everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to parse a new file would be to hook into the uploadfield save method, for the FileIframeField you can do that by sub classing it and overwriting save()

(in SilverStripe 3 there is a new class called UploadField, in UploadField you would need to overwrite `UploadField->upload(SS_HTTPRequest $request)`, and the file there would be accesable like this: `$tmpfile = $request->postVar($this->getName());` )

below, and example on how to do it in FileIframeField:

```
class myFileIFrameField extends FileIFrameField {
    public function save($data, $form) {
        if (
            !isset($data['FileSource'])
            || ($data['FileSource'] == 'new' && (!isset($_FILES['Upload']) || !$_FILES['Upload']))
            || ($data['FileSource'] == 'existing' && (!isset($data['ExistingFile']) || !$data['ExistingFile']))
        ) {
            $form->sessionMessage(_t('FileIFrameField.NOSOURCE', 'Please select a source file to attach'), 'required');
            Director::redirectBack();
            return;
        }
        $fileContent = false;
        if($data['FileSource'] == 'new') {
            $fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['Upload']['tmp_name']);
        }
        elseif($data['FileSource'] == 'existing') {
            $fileObject = DataObject::get_by_id('File', $data['ExistingFile']);
            $fileContent = file_get_contents($fileObject->getFullPath());
        }
        if ($fileContent) {
            // parse the $fileContent here
        }
        // if you want to still save the file into a relation, 
        //meaning if you want to have the actually FileIframeField behaviour still in tact then call 
        return parent::save($data, $form);
        // other wise, if you do not want to save the relation and you don't want to save the file to the server
        // thenn do NOT call parent::save, just do:
        // Director::redirectBack();
    } 
}
```